# Finding and deleting duplicate files in a folder

Tags: python, file-system

The following code aims to identify and delete duplicate files in a folder. At first, files are compared by size, and then (if needed) by hash.

The helper function `sort_duplicates` determines which file of the group of duplicates to keep. I have skipped the part of the code dealing with CLI.

As a self-learner of computer science, I would very appreciate any feedback.

Code is written on Python 3.6.4

```
import os
import hashlib
import collections
import copy 

import test_duplicates

def calculate_hash(file):
      """
      file: path to a file object

      Returns a hash of a provided file object
      """
      md5 = hashlib.md5()
      with open(file, 'rb') as fh:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: fh.read(4098), b''):
                  md5.update(chunk)
      return md5.hexdigest()

def sort_duplicates(duplicates):
      """
      duplicates: sequence of groups of duplicates
      returns two list of the duplicates divided by the rule described in 
      'find_duplicates'
      """

      duplicates = copy.deepcopy(duplicates)
      to_keep = []
      to_delete = []
      for group in duplicates:
            file = [file for file in group if ('cop') not in file][0]
            if file:
                  to_keep.append(file)
                  group.remove(file)
                  to_delete.extend(group)
            else:
                  to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
                  to_delete.extend(group)
      return to_keep, to_delete

def find_duplicates(directory, recursive=True, 
                    exclude_hidden=False, delete=True):
      """returns
            list of duplicates grouped in sets by common hash
            list of duplicates proposed to delete
            list of duplicated proposed to keep

      to_keep contains an arbitrary duplicate from each group of duplicates if
              path of the duplicate does not contain string 'cop'
              if such duplicate does not exist to_keep collects any arbitrary 
              duplicate from the group
      to_delete contains the rest of the duplicates
      """

      duplicates = collections.defaultdict(set)
      sizes_dict = collections.defaultdict(set)

      # filter by size   
      for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            if exclude_hidden:
                  filenames = (filename for filename in filenames
                               if not filename.startswith('.'))
            for filename in filenames:    
                  path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                  sizes_dict[os.path.getsize(path)].add(path)
            if not recursive:
                  break

      groups = [values for values in sizes_dict.values()
                if len(values) > 1]

      for group in groups:
            for item in group:
                  duplicates[calculate_hash(item)].add(item)

      duplicates = [values for values in duplicates.values()
                    if len(values) > 1]

      if not duplicates:
            print('No duplicates has been found')
            return None

      print('----Found following groups of duplicates: ----------------------')
      for group in duplicates:
            print(' - '.join(str(duplicate) for duplicate in group), end='\n')
      print()

      if not delete:
            return 

      to_keep, to_delete = sort_duplicates(duplicates)

      print('----Following files from the list of duplicates will be kept:')
      print(*to_keep, sep='\n', end='\n')
      print()
      print('----Following files from the list of duplicates will be deleted:')
      print(*to_delete, sep='\n')

      for path in to_delete:
            os.remove(path)

      print('Done')

      return duplicates, to_keep, to_delete

if __name__ == '__main__':
      test_duplicates.make_files('/tmp/d')
      find_duplicates('/tmp/d')
```

Output:

```
----Found following groups of duplicates: ----------------------
/tmp/d/2 - /tmp/d/copied/2
/tmp/d/copied/4 - /tmp/d/4
/tmp/d/3 - /tmp/d/copied/3
/tmp/d/copied/0 - /tmp/d/0
/tmp/d/copied/1 - /tmp/d/1

----Following files from the list of duplicates will be kept:
/tmp/d/2
/tmp/d/4
/tmp/d/3
/tmp/d/0
/tmp/d/1

----Following files from the list of duplicates will be deleted:
/tmp/d/copied/2
/tmp/d/copied/4
/tmp/d/copied/3
/tmp/d/copied/0
/tmp/d/copied/1
Done
```

There is `test_duplicates` module.

```
import py.path
import random


from duplicates import find_duplicates


def make_files(directory):
      """
      Creates dummy objects in a given directory:
         10 unique file objects in the parent directory
         copies of the first 5 objects in the subfolder 'copied'
         changed copies (added empty string) of second 5 objects in
                  the subfolder copied

         returns: mapping of dublicate objects
                  list of objects to keep
                  list of objects to deleted

      """

      dir_path = py.path.local(directory)
      copied_path = dir_path.join('copied')
      copied_path.ensure(dir=True)
      changed_path = dir_path.join('changed')
      changed_path.ensure(dir=True)
      duplicates, paths, to_delete = [], [], []

      for ind in range(10):
            path = dir_path.join(str(ind))
            path.write(random.randrange(ind * 10 - 10, ind * 10), ensure=True)

            paths.append(path)
            assert path.check()

      # copy first 5 files into the subfolder 'copy'
      for path in paths[:5]:
            path_copy = copied_path.join(path.basename)
            path.copy(path_copy)
            paths.append(path_copy)
            to_delete.append(path_copy)
            duplicates.append({str(path), str(path_copy)})
            assert path_copy.check()

      # copy second 5 files and add empty string to each of them:
      for path in paths[5:10]:
            path_changed = changed_path.join(path.basename)
            path.copy(path_changed)
            path_changed.write('\n', mode='a')
            paths.append(path_changed)
            assert path_changed.check()

      to_keep = [str(path) for path in paths[:5]]     
      paths.extend((copied_path, changed_path))      
      files = sorted(list(dir_path.visit()))
      assert files == sorted(paths)

      return duplicates, to_keep, to_delete


def test_duplicates(tmpdir):
      """Compares received and expected results of find_duplicate function"""

      exp_duplicates, exp_to_keep, exp_to_delete = make_files(tmpdir)
      rec_duplicates, rec_to_keep, rec_to_delete = find_duplicates(
                                tmpdir, recursive=True, delete=True)
      assert len(exp_duplicates) == len(rec_duplicates)
      for group in rec_duplicates:
            assert group in exp_duplicates

      assert sorted(exp_to_keep) == sorted(rec_to_keep)
      assert sorted(exp_to_delete) == sorted(rec_to_delete)

      no_duplicates = tmpdir.join('copied')
      assert find_duplicates(no_duplicates) == None
```

Comment: You said you left out the CLI, therefore you should explain how to call your code. Having a test is great for this, so everything should be fine by now.

Comment: If the files are very large, you might speed it up by checking for the file sizes and the content of the first 100 bytes

Comment: Duplicate Files Deleter Program is superb to find and delete duplicate files from your computer. It searches throughout your computer, create a list of duplicate files and present them before you for deciding what you want to do with these files. A great way to free space of your disks. If you will try you will love it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I think you should make a `chunk_file` function, so your code is more DRY.

  This would mean splitting `calculate_hash` and `chunk_file` into two.
- I think you should be able to pass what type of hash you want `calculate_hash` to return. This is as you can have hash-collisions.
- `find_duplicates` should be split into more functions.

  - You should make a `files_under` function that finds all the files under a specific directory.
  - You should make a `filter_hidden` function, so you can change the input of `find_duplicates`, rather than relying on `find_duplicates` to do everything.
  - `find_duplicates` shouldn't have the printing code in it. This is as printing filtered duplicates isn't about finding duplicates.
- Rather than using `if not recursive: break` I'd filter the input to the loop.
- I wouldn't build a `groups` intermarry list. As you're doubling the amount of memory you're using for no viable gain.
- I'd merge your `duplicates` and `sizes_dict` code into a loop. And so they are the same variable. This is as you're doing the same thing over both the things. And carrying on the way you are no is hard to extend.
- I would use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) so that you have an easier to use object, than a string.

I changed your code, however didn't implement all of it. I find `sort_duplicates` to be quite confusing, and so left that as it is.

Below are my changes:

```
import functools
import os
import pathlib


def chunk_file(file_path, chunk_size=None):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        if chunk_size is None:
            chunk_size = file._CHUNK_SIZE
        while True:
            data = file.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


def calculate_hash(file_path, hash):
    hash_object = hash()
    for chunk in chunk_file(file_path):
        hash_object.update(chunk)
    return hash_object.hexdigest()


def files_under(directory, recursive=True):
    walk = os.walk(directory):
    if not recursive:
        walk = [next(walk)]

    for root, _, file_names in walk
        root = pathlib.Path(root)
        for file_name in file_names:
            yield root / file_name


def filter_hidden(paths):
    for path in paths:
        if not path.name.startswith('.'):
            yield path


def sort_duplicates(duplicates):
    """
    duplicates: sequence of groups of duplicates
    returns two list of the duplicates divided by the rule described in 
    'find_duplicates'
    """

    duplicates = copy.deepcopy(duplicates)
    to_keep = []
    to_delete = []
    for group in duplicates:
        file = [file for file in group if ('cop') not in file][0]
        if file:
              to_keep.append(file)
              group.remove(file)
              to_delete.extend(group)
        else:
              to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
              to_delete.extend(group)
    return to_keep, to_delete


def find_duplicates(directory, recursive=True,
                    exclude_hidden=False, delete=True):
    methods = [
        lambda path: path.stat().st_size,
        functools.partial(calculate_hash, hash=hashlib.md5),
        functools.partial(calculate_hash, hash=hashlib.sha256)
    ]

    prev = {None: set(paths)}
    for method in methods:
        new = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for group in prev.values():
            if len(group) <= 1:
                continue

            for item in group:
                new[method(item)].add(item)
        prev = new
    return prev
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have learned a lot from your answer! I was also considering using a path objects instead of a string, in particular by using `py.path` module, as it implements `path.computehash` method. I have tried to compare performances of the custom `compute_hash` function and `py.path.computehash` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276339/unreasonably-large-values-of-timing-of-hash-functions), but I assume I made some mistake as the timing results are unreasonably large. If you have time,  please, take a look.

Comment: The way you limited the non-recursive search by using the first outcome of the `next` function in `files_under` function is very neat. In this function, you yield the `root / file_name`, as far as I understand, in this way you obtain the full path of the file. Could I use this method instead of `os.path.join` everywhere, or are there some limitations? I also searched for `_CHUNK_SIZE` attribute in the documentation but found only [chunk](http://bit.ly/2DucFqP) module. From my understanding, it deals only with certain kinds of media files. So, `_CHUNK_SIZE` must be based on something else?

Comment: @OzRamsay Thank you, :) Yes `root / file_name` is a high-level alturnate to `os.path.join`. As far as I know there are no limitations. I used `dir(file)`, and noticed a `_CHUNK_SIZE` variable, and so thought using Python's default chunk size to be a reasonable default. I don't think it's documented, as it is also a private field.

Comment: making the search recursive or not with `pathlib.Path` is even [simpler](https://gist.github.com/vadella/7ccd66ea12278acb398b7076b3462efa).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is generally speaking nice-looking if I may say so. One thing that caught my eye is your `sort_duplicates` function. This one seems a bit convoluted and messy.

More specifically:

1. The list comprehension will throw an Error if the list comes back empty (`[][0]` -> `IndexError`). As a result, checking for `if file` does not make sense. It would have already failed.
2. An entire list comprehension is not needed if you just want the first item. Use `next` instead; it would be much faster and can provide you with a default value in case nothing is found.
3. The `if` and `else` blocks contain the same code, so... You do not need them. There is no reason to check for something if your decisions will not be influenced by the check.
4. In the now meaningless `else` there is a `group.pop(file)` when `file` does not exist. What's up with that?
5. The recommended indentation is only 4 spaces. You are using 6 thus making the nested blocks look too *isolated*.

So I would re-write as:

```
def sort_duplicates(duplicates):
    """
    duplicates: sequence of groups of duplicates
    returns two list of the duplicates divided by the rule described in 
    'find_duplicates'
    """

    duplicates = copy.deepcopy(duplicates)
    to_keep = []
    to_delete = []
    for group in duplicates:
        file = next((file for file in group if 'cop' not in file), None)
        if file is not None:
            to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
            to_delete.extend(group)
    return to_keep, to_delete
```

I will be updating my answer if I see anything else worth pointing out.

---

Based on your comments below, we can make further arrangements to code in a *fall-back* scenario:

```
def sort_duplicates(duplicates):
    """
    duplicates: sequence of groups of duplicates
    returns two list of the duplicates divided by the rule described in 
    'find_duplicates'
    """

    duplicates = copy.deepcopy(duplicates)
    to_keep = []
    to_delete = []
    file, prev_file = '', ''
    for group in duplicates:
        file = next((file for file in group if 'cop' not in file), prev_file)
        if file != prev_file:
            to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
        else:
            to_keep.append(group.pop())
        to_delete.extend(group)
        prev_file = file
    return to_keep, to_delete
```

*Note that I cannot properly test the above and as such there might be small bugs that you would have to ammend. Howeverm the important thing for me is that you understand the logic.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable results.              file = [file for file in group if ('cop') not in file][0]
            if file:
                  to_keep.append(file)
                  group.remove(file)
                  to_delete.extend(group)
            else:
                  to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
                  to_delete.extend(group)

Comment: @OzRamsay You are welcome. Is there a reason you posted that code in the comment?

Comment: Yes, In regards to your remark 3: I wanted to keep only one file of the group of duplicates. To choose such file I add filenames which do not contain string 'cop' (to exclude filenames such as 'copy1' or 'copied') to the list 'files'. If the list is not empty I choose an arbitrary name from the list (it happens to be the first one). If there are no such names (i.e. all names have the string 'cop') I can choose any name from the entire group. In this case, it will be the last processed filename which is stored as variable 'file' from the previous list comprehension. How do you think about that?

Comment: @OzRamsay Well, I cannot comment on the idea because that is just **what** you want to do. The **how** is where I come in and I can tell you that the code you had **did not** do that. If the `list`comes back empty your code raises an Error... There is no *falling back* to the previous `file` value.

Comment: Now I see that I haven't fully understood your remark. The problem is that 'else' part will never work.  Thank you again for the clarification!

Comment: @OzRamsay Take a [look](https://repl.it/repls/ThankfulCommonGrayreefshark)! This might make it even clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71850/discussion-between-ozramsay-and-ev-kounis).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't analyze  the whole program carefully, so this review is not complete from my point of view.

**Use the Right Library Calls**

If you read/write files be carefully that you do it in the right way. You can `open` a file in *text mode* or *binary mode*. If you compare arbitrary files then  *binary mode* may be the correct one, check the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). If text mode is the wrong one, which test case could demonstrate this? Maybe a file containing `\n\r\n` and a file containing `\r\n\n` contain both three bytes, are different in byte mode and maybe the same in text mode, because they both contain two empty lines, but I did not check this (`\n`is the *newline*-character and `\r` is the *carriage return* character.

**Improve your Algorithm**

Your program could do the search for duplicate files  more efficiently. A file can only be the duplicate of another  file if both files have the same length. The length of a file can be easily retrieved from the operating system. So first get the name and size of every file you want to investigate and group them by their sizes. Only if  a group contains more then one file you have investigate this group further. This can help to avoid the reading of a lot of large files.

If you have two large file of equal size and large parts of them are not  equal then if you compare the file at some random positions then there is a high probability that they differ at that positions. If they differ then you have avoided to read the whole file. The `seek` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes)  changes the stream position. Only if the files are identical on these random positions you continue with comparing the hash of  the whole files.

**Don't Use Magic Constants**

You use the *magic string constant*  `'cop'` somewhere in your code. You shouldn't use such magical constant. If you need them than define a global variable, choose an appropriate name and maybe write an explanation in the comment. Or if it is not really a constant then you should supply it as argument of the function. In your case I think either it should be supplied as argument or you define some kind of test mode for you program (e.g. by setting a global variable `TEST_MODE=True`) where this global variable for `'cop'` is used.

There is another *magic constant* in your code: 4098. Again you should define a global variable with a descriptive name. We have:

```
4098 Byte = 4 KByte + 2 Byte
```

Are you sure that 4098 is the value you want to use?

In your special case it seems that you have a special treatment for path names that contain `/copied/` but you didn't program that. I think you should (almost) always try to program your code so that it actually does what you want. This makes it simpler to understand what you do.

**Different Names for Different Variables**

I also don't like a statement where the same variable name has two different meanings like in

```
file = [file for file in group if ('cop') not in file][0]
```

`file` on the right of the `=` expreession is  a different variable then on the left of `=`. Better write

```
file = [f for f in group if ('cop') not in f][0]
```

or something similar, this makes it easier to understand.

**Don't Use `deepcopy` Automatically**

You use `copy.deepcopy`. This may be more deep than necessary. You actually only modify the sets, so it will be sufficient to change lines like

```
group.remove(file)
to_delete.extend(group)
```

and

```
to_keep.append(group.pop(file))
to_delete.extend(group)
```

to

```
g = copy.copy(group)
g.remove(file)
to_delete.extend(g)
```

and

```
g = copy.copy(group)
to_keep.append(g.pop(file))
to_delete.extend(g)
```

or you replace

```
duplicates = copy.deepcopy(duplicates)
```

by

```
duplicates = [set(group) for group in duplicates]
```

It depends on the types of objects if `deepcopy` makes actually a copy of the objects, too. For your algorithm a copy of the object is not necessary. In case of strings it seems to be depend on the Python implementation if the are copies of strings made (see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124011/754550)). The Python implementation on my notebook does not make copies of the string but the strings of the `deepcopy` point to the same object:

```
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> print(id(x), id(y))
50516992 50516992
```

But if you use your functions for list of sets of mutable objects then copies of these objects will be made and this is not necessary and may slow down a program. But I admin that in your case where  you read a lot of files from the disk this will not have an influence of the overall performance of the program.

**Don't Relate the Description and Names of a Function and its Variables to Code that isn't Related**

*Ev.Kounis* already showed you some [serious problems of *sort_duplicate* function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185290/12462). 
I will concentrate on non technical aspects. I dont like the  naming and description of the `sort_duplicates`. You are talking about files and duplicate but this function is not about files and duplicates, but it is about list of sets of strings and if you wouldn't have this `'cop'` thing then it would be about a list of sets arbitrary objects and not even about strings.  And you want to choose one representative of each set and return a list of these chosen representatives and a list of the remaining group elements. There is nothing about duplicates. And so I would change your naming and description. This makes it easier for a reader to understand the function and makes it also easier to reuse these function in another context or use it in a library.

Comment: edited the post: some notes about the constant 4098 used in the code